# Find a way to call Blueprint Container for prototype bean

Tags: java, osgi, apache-karaf, osgi-bundle, blueprint-osgi

I'm moving from a Spring context to a blueprint bean manager on OSGi Karaf, and I cannot find way to call blueprint "context". For example, in Java Spring, I call `ApplicationContext` with method `context.getBean(MyBean.class)` and get a prototype instance of `MyBean`.

Now I have a `blueprint.xml` with my prototype bean configuration, and can't work with that in Java code. Is there something like that in blueprint?

Comment: Have you looked at SCR (or components?) They automatically register as an OSGi service and give you the ability to get the handle to the instance of the java class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a class that accepts the blueprint container as an argument:

```
    <bean class="com.acme.FooImpl">
      <property name="container" ref="blueprintContainer"/>
    </bean>
```

- [Blueprint specification](https://docs.osgi.org/specification/osgi.cmpn/7.0.0/service.blueprint.html)
- [BlueprintContainer javadoc](https://docs.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v42/org/osgi/service/blueprint/container/BlueprintContainer.html)